# Non-relativistic limit of the Dirac equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, dirac-equation

How to recover non-relativistic limit of the Dirac equation
$$\left( i\gamma^{\mu}\mathcal{D}_{\mu} - m \right)\Psi(x) = 0$$
where $\mathcal{D}_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu} + iqA_{\mu}$. I do not assume that the vector potential $A_{\mu}$ is zero, but I have a particle in central potential and magnetic field. During derivation please highlight where does the non-relativistic assumptions is used and how.
I have found some notes [here](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~dine/ph217/217_dirac_nr.pdf), but I don't understand why can we Taylor expand this expression
$$\frac{1}{E + m -qA^0}\vec{\sigma}\cdot(\vec{p} - q\vec{A}) \approx \frac{1}{E+m}\vec{\sigma}\cdot(\vec{p} - q\vec{A})  + \frac{1}{(E+m)^2}qA^0\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}$$
around $qA^0 = 0$ and neglect $\vec{A}$ in the second term.

Comment: The reason for neglecting $\vec A$ is that the magnetic field $\nabla \times \vec A$ is a factor of $v/c$ smaller than the electric field $-\nabla A^0$ (for a static vector potential). See also the answer to [Why are magnetic fields so much weaker than electric?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/128512/why-are-magnetic-fields-so-much-weaker-than-electric)

Answer (score 1):

The essential reason is that the "$E$" in your equation has no non-relativistic limit. This can be seen more clearly by separating out the rest-mass-energy $mc^2$ and writing $E = mc^2 + H$, with $H$ comprising the total of the kinetic and internal energy. The "$mc^2$" part blows up to infinity as $c$ goes to infinity.

On the other hand $H$ has a non-relativistic limit. At the same time, the mass in non-relativistic theory can be treated as the non-relativistic limit of the "moving mass" $M = E/c^2$. So, to get a non-relativistic version of Dirac requires actually *extending* the Poincaré group from 10 dimensions to 11, by replacing $E$ by $M$ and $H$, treating them as independent.

So, the confusion arises from confusing $E$ and $H$. The shifting from $E$ to $H$ is precisely what is done with the Foldy-Wouthuysen transformation.

In place of the mass shell identity
$$\frac{E^2}{c^2} - ||^2 = (mc)^2,$$
you then have *two* identities:
$$||^2 - 2MH + \frac{1}{c^2}H^2 = 0, \quad M - \frac{1}{c^2}H = m.$$
If you solve for $H$, you will see more clearly the connection to non-relativistic theory ... and you will *also* see more clearly what that extra 11th dimension in the symmetry group reflects:
$$H = \frac{||^2}{m + M}.$$
Compare to the non-relativistic case:
$$H = \frac{||^2}{2m} + U$$
where $U$ is the internal energy - i.e. the "kinetic energy" arising from the kinetics of the internal constituency of a body ... except now, it's being generalized and treated as a thing in its own right that potentially applies even to elementary bodies. So, it's the rest frame value of $H$, just as $m$ (the rest-mass) is the rest frame value of $M$. Substituting into the equations for the two invariants leads to the following modified form:
$$||^2 - 2MH + \frac{1}{c^2}H^2 = -2mU + \frac{1}{c^2}U^2, \quad μ ≡ M - \frac{1}{c^2}H = m - \frac{1}{c^2}U.$$
The drop-down from extended Poincaré-11 to ordinary Poincaré-10 then corresponds to setting $U = 0$.

On the other hand, the non-relativistic limit corresponds to setting $1/c^2$ to $0$. The non-relativistic limit of $M$, $m$ and $μ$ are all $m$, the mass, with all 11 dimensions of the symmetry group kept intact.

In Relativity, the following is invariant:
$$E dt - ·d,$$
where $d = (dx,dy,dz)$. If you make the above replacements, you get
$$H dt - ·d + μc^2 dt.$$
To make a meaningful non-relativistic limit out of this, you have to throw in the proper time, which we can denote $s$ and rewrite it as:
$$H dt - ·d + μc^2 dt - μc^2 ds.$$
Then, you can define a new coordinate $u = c^2(s - t)$ - i.e. the time dilation, itself, ramped up by $c^2$ and write:
$$H dt - ·d - μdu.$$

Now, you have a new invariant that you can take the non-relativistic limit for. In place of the Minkowski invariant
$$ds^2 = dt^2 - \frac{|d|^2}{c^2}$$
are now two invariants:
$$|d|^2 + 2 dt du + \frac{1}{c^2}du^2, \quad ds = dt + \frac{1}{c^2}du.$$
This, too, has a non-relativistic limit:
$$|d|^2 + 2 dt du, \quad ds = dt.$$
The 11th generator in the extended Poincaré group is actually the translation on the $u$ coordinate. Since everything else is $u$-invariant, then ... by the Noether Theorem ... there is a conserved quantity. That's $μ$.

In the non-relativistic limit, $μ$ is the "central charge" that arises when you centrally extend the Galilei group to the Bargmann group - which is actually what the correct symmetry group for non-relativistic theory is, not Galilei!

Extend the operator correspondences appropriately:
$$H ⇔ iħ \frac{∂}{∂t}, \quad  ⇔ -iħ∇, \quad μ ⇔ -iħ\frac{∂}{∂u},$$
replace the $$ and $β$ matrices to rewrite
$$δH - · - εμ ⇔ iħ\left(δ\frac{∂}{∂t} + ·∇ + ε\frac{∂}{∂u}\right),$$
for units $δ$, $ = \left(γ^1, γ^2, γ^3\right)$, $ε$, endowing them with a suitably-defined algebra (which will - in fact - be isomorphic to the complexified Dirac algebra), and add in the eigenvalue equation
$$μψ = -iħ\frac{∂ψ}{∂u},$$
for the central charge. Restricting to the ordinary Poincaré group, for Relativity, by setting $U = 0$ and $μ = m$ produces:
$$iħ\left(δ\frac{∂ψ}{∂t} + ·∇ψ + ε\frac{∂ψ}{∂u}\right) = 0, \quad mψ = -iħ\frac{∂ψ}{∂u}$$
which will be equivalent to the Dirac equation. Taking the limit $1/c^2 = 0$, on the other hand, will produce a result equivalent to the Schrödinger equation.

You can also add in a coupling with the electromagnetic potential. In that case, the non-relativistic version will be the Pauli-Schrödinger equation.

Note that shifting from $E$ to $H$ by subtracting off $mc^2$ corresponds adding a phase factor $\exp(±imc^2/ħ)$ to $ψ$, depending on which direction you're going in.

I demonstrate this, in detail - here [Morphing The Dirac-Maxwell Equation To The Pauli-Schrödinger Equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/694598/issue-in-deriving-non-relativistic-dirac-equation/782473#782473) and in the opposite direction, here [Morphing The Schrödinger Equation To The Klein-Gordon Equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/757828/is-the-schr%c3%b6dinger-equation-incompatible-with-special-relativity-if-so-why/781872#781872).

Needless to say, none of this was available in during the time Schrödinger devised his equation. He didn't know that Bargmann was the correct symmetry group for non-relativistic theory, rather than Galileo, nor that its natural geometric interpretation is 5D, not 4D; and even up to the present day there is still not a proper understanding that the correct symmetry group for Relativity is not the Poincaré group, but its (trivial) central extension to the extended Poincaré group.